# Посоветуйте скриптовый движок

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, скриптовый движок для .Net. Желательно с отладчиком, автокомплитом, подсветкой синтаксиса. Язык лучше бы C#.

Comment: Если Вам, скажем, нужны отчёты, можете использовать Crystal Reports for .NET, он поддерживает скрипты. А зачем может понадобиться скриптовый движок вообще - непонятно. Может, Вам нужна IDE?

Comment: Что за движок? Для сайта? Среда разработки? Сервис отчетов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам давно использую [CSScript](http://csscript.net) (полноценный C# в роли скриптового двига). Как уже писали выше, есть бинд для LUA - [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/). Стоит еще посмотреть вот на эту новую сказку - [Microsoft Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/roslyn) (как основа для реализации своего языка). Просто и быстро - [Conscript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Conscript.aspx). Движков разных достаточно много, выбор зависит от того, какую функциональность ты от него хочешь получить.

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вас, однако для популярных скриптовых языков существуют биндинги или даже полные реализации под C#.

В моих проектах, которые требовали присутствия некоторого скриптового языка в самом приложении, я обычно пользовался [**IronPython.**](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) Особенно удобна интеграция его и C# в версии .NET 4.0, поскольку появился полноценный `dynamic`.

Касательно других возможных вариантов - у Lua существует функциональный [бинд](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275) под C#. *Да чего там говорить, можно и Javascript прикручивать к шарпу, было бы желание.*

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет [F#](http://www.tryfsharp.org/)? Есть в составе 2010 студии, куча книжек и мануалов, очень тесная интеграция с .Net.

Comment: Очень интересно, кто придумал **полноценный функциональный** язык обозвать скриптовым.

Comment: Что не отменяет его возможности исполнятся в рантайме.